# Why am I getting the error "non-template 'f' used as template"

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I'm trying to understand where to use `template` and `typename` and I came across a problem I can't quite get around. I have a template-function `f<T>` which uses the type passed to it (which will be a class) to call the template-member-function `.f<T>`. I think my use of `typename` in the function body is correct, however, I keep getting the following error:

> source.cpp: In function `'void f()'`:
>   source.cpp:11:19: error: non-template `'f'` used as template
>   source.cpp:11:19: note: use `'typename T::C::template f'` to indicate that it is a template

```
struct A {
  struct C {
     template <typename T> void f() {}
  };
};

template <typename T> void f() {

  typename T::C::f<int>();

}

int main() {

  f<A>();

}
```

Notice how on the last error it advises to use `'typename T::C::template f'` instead. So I made the following change in accordance:

```
// ...
typename T::C::template f<int>();
// ...
```

I did as it said, but then I received the next line of error:

> error: no class template named `'f'` in `'struct A::C'`

I believe this error is incorrect in that there *is* in fact a public template function named `f` in `struct A::C`. What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming we make `f` `static` so it can be called without an instance, you don't need `typename` because you're not creating any ambiguities with a dependent type (i.e. `C` can't be a variable because you use it with `::` just after). Here is the correct syntax:

```
struct A {
  struct C {
     template <typename T>
     static void f() {}
  };
};

template <typename T> void f() {
  T::C::template f<int>();
}
```

If you wanted not to make it static, you'd create a `A::C` and use `.template f<int>()`:

```
struct A {
  struct C {
     template <typename T>
     static void f() {}
  };
};

template <typename T> void f() {
  typename T::C c;
//^^^^^^^^ Now we DO need typename to disambiguate.

  c.template f<int>();
}
```

Comment: What if we took away `static`, what would we have to do then to invoke `f`?

Comment: So you mean `T::C->template f<int>();`?

Comment: Great answer, but I have another question: How does the `static` modifier allow `f` to be called without having to supply an instance?

Comment: @user6607 that's what `static` means in this context. It makes a function in a class definition not a member function, so that it's not associated with a particular instance, and it can be called without having to first create an object. `static` class functions do not have a `this` pointer.

Comment: @user6607 it is a basic C++ concept that you can read more about online or in any C++ book.